# Delay in receiving DialogFlow results with very short sentences

Tags: dialogflow-es

I stream from the microphone of an Android client to a nodejs server
(built by me), which forwards the audio to a DialogFlow agent.
The streaming code of the nodejs server is based on this snippet: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/detect-intent-stream#streaming_detect_intent

The server in nodejs first receives the intermediate results (with the words spotted by the automatic speech
recognition - ASR) and then the final result of DialogFlow (with NLU
analysis). The connection protocol between the Android client and the nodejs
server is websocket.

The problem that I am facing is that
when I stream the audio of short sentences (in my case the
words in Italian "sì"/"no"), the final result of dialogFlow
sometimes comes with a delay that is close to 10 seconds.

I measured the delay of the final DialogFlow result from when the first partial ASR result arrives.
So my experiments are carried on like this:

- I open the microphone and I start speaking (I just say "sì" or "no")
- the first intermediate result arrives (the timer starts)
- the final result of DialogFlow arrives (the timer stops)

The intermediate results of the speech recognition arrive almost
immediately, that is, with a very low delay.

As for the delay with which the final result of DialogFlow arrives,
about once in two the result arrives within 4 seconds, which is
acceptable, otherwise it takes longer (in the worst case even with 10
or 11 seconds of delay). In the latter case, the delay is not acceptable
as the user experience is too slow.

Again, I must say that this problem is found only in extremely short
sentences. With sentences consisting of words of a just few syllables, the
delay of DialogFlow is always negligible, and everything is fine.

I also tried with the English models, but the sentences consisting of
"yes" and "no" suffer from the same delay. I also did some tests with
models other than the default one (in particular I tried the model
`command_and_search`, which is described as "Best for short queries
such as voice commands or voice search"), but without luck.

I understand that the use of such short sentences as "yes" and "no" is
not the most frequent use case for a DialogFlow agent, however I
believe that in certain circumstances it is useful (sometimes
necessary) to use them.

So I ask if anyone has experienced this problem and knows how to overcome
it.